# Windows 10 electron forge icon isn't working

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-forge

I'm trying to publish my electron app, And I'm using the following code in the package.json:

```
  "packagerConfig": {
    "icon": "./src/icon.ico"
  },
```

But when I use electron forge and look into out/win32-x64 directory, the single executable is the default electron icon, when I run it the icon appears both in the app top right corner, as well as the shortcut icon.

I've scoured the internet and couldn't find a fix for this.

Heres the github with the code: https://github.com/Paxxous/Extremely-minamilistic-text-editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so it was just a weird bug that I found, You just have to move the exe out of the directory and then it would show. (Though also make sure to remove the out folder just in case)

Comment: So crazy. Thank you! That is a really weird bug :-D

Answer (score 1):

no need for '.icon' suffix, see https://www.electronforge.io/guides/create-and-add-icons#windows-and-macos

> electron-forge will automatically add the correct extension for each platform, thus appending .ico or .icns to the path is not required.

Comment: Thanks man! Haven't really been working with electron for a bit but I've compiled everything and it seems to work nicely.